# matplotlib scatter with non-sequential label colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot a scatter plot with color based on a label vector `y` (of size 3). Labels are from the set {0,1,5}.  But the below code is not giving me the intended plot.  The colors are not plotted correctly. Instead of yellow, black is plotted, and no red is plotted only blue (that also on a black larger point).

```
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs;
import numpy as np;
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;
import matplotlib.colors as clrs;

X,y = make_blobs(n_samples=100, n_features = 2, centers = 5,  cluster_std = 4.8, random_state=1000);
tr_sz = 40;
y = np.ones(y.shape,dtype=np.uint8);
y[tr_sz:] = 0;
ind1 = np.random.choice(tr_sz,size=12);
y[ind1] = 5
colors = ['yellow', 'red', 'blue'];
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(3.25,3));
print y;
ax1.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1], s=y+1, c=y,     cmap=clrs.ListedColormap(colors));
fig.savefig('test.pdf');
```

Comment: please include a self contained code segment which can be executed.

Comment: should be fine now

Comment: There are no zeros in your `y`.

Comment: it seems, i copied the wrong code.  i added new code which is working. can you check now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of problems

1. Your colormap will be created from your list and will therefore have no way to know that `1` should map to `red` - it simply maps the `max` of your data (5) to `blue` and the `min` (0) to yellow, interpolating for the rest, so `1` maps to yellow also.  If you replace 1 with 3 in your data (e.g. by using the line `y = np.array([k if k!=1 else 3 for k in y ])`), you will see red appear.
2. Your points are very small - particularly for the case where `y==0` (your marker radius will be only 1).  In this case, the line around the marker is what you see, rather than the fill colour.  Where you think you see black - your marker is in fact yellow, just ***very*** small. A way to get round this is simply to multiply the size by a constant factor.

#### Solution

Here's one way to achieve what I think you want (replacing lines 12-15 of your sample):

```
colors = {0:'yellow', 1:'red', 5:'blue'};
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(3.25,3));
print y;
c_arr=[colors[k] for k in y]
ax1.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1], s=(y+1)*20, c=c_arr);
```

#### Output

[image: scatter plot output]